# Android drawable resource does not show up in phone but renders well in eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-activity

I created a drawable resource file named gradient_box.xml as coded below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#000000"
    android:endColor="#ffffff"
    android:angle="0"

    />

<corners android:radius="1000dp" />
<stroke android:width="10dip" android:color="#0000ff" />
</shape>
```

Then created a layout file named button_design.xml in which background of the button is set with above created drawable .The code is as given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_box"
     />



</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout rendered with api-19 in eclipse displays a rectangular button.

But when the app runs on the phone the button has oval shape instead of        rectangular.

Comment: `<corners android:radius="1000dp" />` Isn't **1000dp** an exaggeration?

Comment: ... oval? which oval? It all depends on the relation between your corners size and the button width or height sizes. The corner size should equal **half of the smallest one**, to be `semicircular`.

Comment: An oval was displayed which could it be the effect of corners having 1000dp radius,that was an error.But the rendering in eclipse was different from that on phone.How would anyone explain this?

Comment: The Graphical Editor **isn't reliable** (not always, at least). It should be used just to get an overall idea. But most of the work has to be visualized in your head.

Comment: thanks for clearing the air and reminding that the graphical editor isn't  always reliable.

Comment: it was helpful though.